# How to compute $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{X^+(x)}{x-z}dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> For complex number $z$, let $X(z)=\sqrt{z^2-1}$, $X^{+}(x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0+} X(x+iy)$ where $x, y$ are real numbers, define $f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{X^+(x)}{x-z}\,dx$.
>
> How to compute $f(z)$?

By direct calculation $f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{\sqrt {1-x^2}}{x-z}\,dx$ but then I don't know how to proceed.

Note: it's the third problem of a series of related problems which may help.
[image]

Comment: Your subject line says $\displaystyle f(x)=\int^1_{-1} \frac{X^+(x)}{x-z} \, dx,$ but the expression to the right of the "equals" sign obviously does not define a function of $x. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's $f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{X^+(x)}{x-z}\,dx$ not $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that on the domain $|x|<1$

$$X^+ - X^- = X^+ + X^+ = 2X^+$$

which means that

$$X(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2X^+(x)}{x-z}\:dx$$

Then it follows that $f(z)$ in the problem equals $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{z^2-1}$

Comment: Where does $X(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2X^+(x)}{x-z}\:dx$ come from?

Comment: @CYC the answer to question $1$

Comment: Isn't it $f^{+}(x)+f^{-}(x) = X^{+}(x)$ where  $f(z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{X^{+}(x)}{x-z} \,\, dx$?

Comment: @CYC it seems like you aren't reading your own textbook correctly, or are misunderstanding something I wrote. Again, look at problem $1$, equation $(2)$

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @CYC how can you misread a minus as a plus? It clearly says $f^+(x)-f^-(x) = \phi(x)$

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo from me, but how does $f^{+}(x)-f^{-}(x) = X^{+}(x)$ give us $X(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2X^{+}(x)}{x-z}$?

Comment: @CYC Because $X^-(x) = -X^+(x)$ from problem $2$ equation $(3)$

Comment: @CYC I think I see your confusion. Equations $1$ and $2$ aren't referring to a specific $f$ it's true for all functions if such a $\phi(x)$ were to exist.

Comment: @CYC in other words, you plug in $f=X$ into equation $(2)$ to get the first relationship in my post.

Comment: @CYC no, read my last comment again. I tried to find the $\phi$ for $X$ separately, and coincidentally it was a scalar multiple of the $\phi$ for $f$

Comment: How can we be sure $X(z)$ can be written in the form $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{h(x)}{z-x}$ for some $h(x)$ in the first place? (In order to apply equation (2))

Comment: @CYC because the limit exists and is distinct from the upper plane and lower plane. If the limits were identical then such a $\phi$ would not exist.

Comment: You mean because both limits $X^{+}(x) = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0+} X(x+iy)$ & $X^{-}(x)$ exists and are distinct? I don't see why this implies $X(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{h(x)}{x-z}\,\, dx$ for some $h(x)$, we need such $h(x)$ to exist in the first place in order to deduce $h(x)= X^{+}(x)-X^{-}(x)$ by equation 2.

Comment: @CYC the if and only if would be made obvious from reading the rest of the section, as I'm assuming this is a text on hyperfunctions. If not, consider that it is certainly true that $$f(z) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{f^+(x)-f^-(x)}{x-z}\:dz$$ if the difference of the limits is nonzero on the domain $(-1,1)$ The existence of the function is a nonquestion, just remove it from the situation if it is confusing you.

Comment: Is there a neat proof that $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{f^{+}-f^{-}(x)}{x-z}=f(z)$? Or is there some reference about the existence of $h(x)$? I'm not reading any textbook, nor have I ever heard of hyperfunction, but just try solving this problem from a past exam from Tokyo University PhD entrance exam.

Comment: @CYC that's what question $1$ asks you to prove!